# Does projection change which points are inside a 2d bounding box?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say you have a dataset of arbitrarily collected datapoints in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

You have an arbitrary, potentially rotated, rectangle (defined by 8 corner points) which is a 2D object defined in $\mathbb{R^3}$. We define datapoints to be "inside" the rectangle in one of two ways:

1. We project the datapoints along the hyperplane of the rectangle, and now can use [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-2d-point-is-within-a-polygon) algorithms to determine if a 2D projected datapoint is "inside" the 2D rectangle.
2. We project the corner points of the rectangle to the XY unit axes, thus defining a new rectangle in $\mathbb{R^2}$. We project the datapoints to the XY unit axes. Both projections basically just remove the z-components. Now we can run the same 2D-point-enclosure algorithms as in 1.

In both cases, will the same points be "inside" and "outside" the rectangle? Can someone argue this rigorously with linear algebra?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how a rectangle would be defined by 8 vertices and not 4, but I think the answer to your question is no. For instance, consider the rectangle (0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1). Then it's projection is the unit square in the XY plane, but the point (1/2, -1, 2) is 'in' the rectangle, but not it's projection.

You could also consider any rectangle perpendicular to the XY plane, then it's projection is a line so any point not actually on the plane of the rectangle cannot possibly be in it's projection.